# Understanding the slit plane and the complex $\sqrt{z}$

Tags: complex-analysis

My book (Gamelin's Complex Analysis) talks about the square and square root functions for complex variables.  I do not understand the slit plane (from $-\infty$ to $0$) for $\sqrt{z}$, and mapping the positive to one side of the slit plane and the negative to the other.

The picture in the book is:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Check out the article in Wikipedia on Riemann surfaces to get a better view of the branch cut , (under examples, $\sqrt{z}$): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_surface

Comment: I looked at that and didn't quite understand it.

Comment: The intersection of the surface with itself is the "slit plane (from −∞ to 0)" shown in your drawing.

Comment: The understanding should be that the square root is single valued with this condition attached.

Comment: How does that condition make it single valued?

Comment: If we pass below the cut we get $-\sqrt{z}$ , that is the other branch of the function.